# Posts reviewing without observing

Tags: discussion

I just reviewed one posts for low-quality posts section.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/160269

Here, You can observe the quality and observation of reviewing.

**Please check once before reviewing.**

[image]

Comment: I wonder where the downvotes come from...

Comment: @7ochem, Mee too. Why the users are giving their valuable downvotes which equal to them

Answer (score 6):

It seems that Manoj does NOT read the question properly. This answer should be deleted. I see, it is deleted now and right action take by the community member.

StackExchange gives us the authority to review all questions and answer content and take action accordingly and it is an honor for all user who has this authority. So request to all user to read the content of every Q&A the post before taking any action during the review.

I hope that all user will take care of his/her action during the review of Q&A and 
 will give more time on reviewing t.

Also, for Teja I don't think about this issue, you need to create a question to Meta where the right action taken by the community member. You already have the privilege to recommend deletion of an answer and also you can create a flag on content, so I don't feel create a question for this issue is worthful.

Comment: Hello Amit. Good afternoon. Yeah I am completely agree with your answer and happy to receiving these kind of responses from you. I am going to delete this question now.

Comment: Why do you want to delete the question? Your question is  on Answer section

Comment: As you said, You dont feel its a worthy question instead of creating a flag na. Thats why only dear. I dont want to bother anyone. And i wanna lear many things from MSE and members.

Comment: Sorry,I miss understood your comment.i thought you talking about main question but now I understand you have talk about this meta question.i suggest you don't need to delete this meta question